# Return #nil in a Guile extension

Tags: c, scheme, guile

I know that there are a couple of singletons around that can be used to quickly return "common" values from Guile C extension functions, like:

```
SCM_UNSPECIFIED
SCM_BOOL_F
```

and others.

I would expect that returning `#nil` from a C function would be just as easy, but I have yet to find the proper constant or the proper way.

Returning NULL is a no-go.

So, **the question is**: how do I return `#nil` from a C extension function?

And if doing so is relatively convoluted, is there a reason for that (e.g. maybe returning `#nil` is not idiomatic in Scheme)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a way, although not necessarily the best one.

There is an:

```
SCM_ELISP_NIL
```

which I was dissing due to the `ELISP` in the name (turns out, with good reasons).

Turns out it returns a proper `#nil` and a cursory check on the C code shows it's not an alias for something more Guile-specific.

My own interpretation is that `#nil` is not idiomatic but something provided for ELISP portability, and I should probably return an empty list instead.